# One of the two fields should be not required after filling one of them

Tags: django

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo_date = forms.CharField(required=True)
    foo_time = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

How can I implement something like this:

if `foo_data` is filled - `foo_time` should be `required=False` and vice versa. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `required=False` for both fields, then check in the [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) method that at least one is filled in.

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo_date = forms.CharField(required=False)
    foo_time = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(FooForm, self).clean()
        if not (cleaned_data.get('foo_date') or cleaned_data.get('foo_time')):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Either foo_date or foo_time is required')
        return cleaned_data
```